# Django restframework unique error not processed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I did not fill in the necessary fields, Django would return a message to the client, but when the field was unique, an error message would appear.

Why didn't Django handle it?

#### models.py

```py
class UserModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sign_up_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    sign_in_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

#### serializers.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=512)
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True, default=False)
    sign_up_date = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    sign_in_date = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = (
            'id', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'is_active', 'sign_up_date', 'sign_in_date',)
```

#### views.py

```py
class SignupView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
```

#### error

```
IntegrityError at /api/signup/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "User_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(test@gmail.com) already exists.
```

[image]

I hope Django can return error messages to the client.

```
{"email": ["already exists"]}
```

Comment: As far as this behavior is concerned, it is correct. Email field has `unique=True` and the db is reporting that as it should. What do expect the outcome to be?

Comment: I hope I can send back to the client `{"email": ["test@gmail.com already exists"]}`, or I can customize the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `UserSerializer` you are declaring some of the model fields again such as `email` etc. By doing that the behavior of the field is not copied from how it was defined on the model. It works as if that behavior has been overridden.

You can drop `email = serializers.EmailField()` and then the default behaviour would kick in and you will get to see the error message corresponding to unique field.

In the same fashion you could drop other fields too which are just replicas of the fields on the model.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you customize the message?

Comment: You can customize the message but then you will have to declare the field yourself and pass the [`UniqueValidator`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator) with custom message.